# AJAX POST Form Always posts Data from the first record in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found this issue is related to my AJAX posting method.  If I post this form using the standard method (action="") it works fine it polulates my database according to which record I select in the list to post.   But when I use the AJAX Post method it will only poplulate the values with the first record on the SQL Results list.  I made my input fields visible and all the posted content is unique and as expected.  Below is the full code.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

/// Check SQL connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {

echo"my error";

die();

}     

// Get the the data from the database

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

// Check database connection first
if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {

echo"my error";

exit(); 
}


   else if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   

echo'

<div class="col-md-3 bid-section">
 
 
<form  action="" method="post" > <!-- Favourites -->
<input type="text" class ="name" name="name" value="'.$row["name"].'">
<input type="text" class ="surname" name="surname" value="'.$row["surname"].'">
<input type="text" class ="country" name="country" value="'.$row["country"].'">

<a   class ="favourite-btn" >
<div class="'.$favicon.'"></div>
</a>
</form>


</div> <!-- Column 3 END -->';
 

  }
}
  
mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
AJAX script
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.favourite-btn').click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
        
        var field1= $('.name').val();
        var field2= $('.surname').val();
        var field3= $('.country').val();
        
                 
        $.post('mydirectory/add_names_sql.php', {name:field1, surname:field2  , country:field3},
        
         // Alert Success
         function(data){
       
        // Alerts the results to this Div
            $('.favourite-btn').html(data);
            
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('.name').val()` is the value of the first element with that class. You need to select the element that's in the same form as the button that was clicked.

```
        var form = $(this).closest("form");
        var field1= form.find('.name').val();
        var field2= form.find('.surname').val();
        var field3= form.find('.country').val();
```

You could also get all the form inputs with:

```
        var formdata = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
```

And in the callback function, you also need to update the appropriate element.

```
form.find('.favourite-btn').html(data);
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar!  I will try this, I have spent days trying to figure this one out :-)

Comment: Darmar where you say  ....closest("form");    Should a class or ID for the Form?  Sorry I am ac omplete newbee

Comment: Any selector can be used. Since your form doesn't have a class, I just used the tag name. An ID wouldn't work, since each form has to have a different ID.

Comment: Sorry for spelling your name wrong.  Thanks that works !!   I will give you the TICK.  However  another Issue I noticed that I thought  may get resolved by this is that when I post the form for one item it also returned the Ajax result (which is an Icon) result for all the ones below  though the data posted is now correct.

Comment: Use `form.find(".favourite-btn").html(data)`

Comment: WOOOOW!!!  You are a Genius!!!!!!   Thats worked too.:-)     I spent days and night on this Thank you!   Now i can get my life back!

Comment: Why wasn't it obvious that this was the same problem? Selectors don't automatically confine themselves to a specific subset of the DOM. If you want to select a particular element, you have to be specific.